# Htaccess Redirect From domain.com/folder1/xxxx to www.domain.com/folder1/xxxx and so on

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, web

I searched all along the web but can't find the code.

I need to redirect all requests that goe to domain.com/folder1 and **its sub-folders** to www.domain.com/folder1/.

When redirected, it should keep the complete URL and just add the www.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: This has been answere about a trillion times alone here on StackOverflow. This is the standard non-www to www rewriting. What is wrong with all those solutions you surely found in your research?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I tried that already but the result is that when I enter domain.com/folder or domain.com/folder/folder2, I am always redirected to domain.com (start page)....

Comment: If that really is the case then the reason is _not_ those rewriting rules, but something else. Check for example if there is some additional rewriting inside the www-host. Or if those requests make sense inside the sss host configuration at all. In general: when debugging issues with redirection it is a very good idea to turn on rewrite logging. It shows you exactly what is going on inside the rewriting module.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tried that already but the result is that when I enter domain.com/folder, I am redirected to domain.com ..

Comment: `^(.*)$` will take that folder path and give it to `$1` so it redirect to that page